# Gutenberg blocks shortcodes compatibility

Tags: php, plugin-development, twitter-bootstrap

I have a custom plugin that will help me in building my layouts using bootstrap.

I'm reading about the [blocks](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/key-concepts/) that are part of the new Gutenberg editor.

I want to understand if the shortcodes and the blocks can be work together, if it's not possible, do i need to rewrite the plugin? Would like to know the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Gutenberg has a block for this. [The Shortcode Block.](https://gogutenberg.com/blocks/shortcode/)

> There are no settings for the shortcode block. You simply have one
>   input box where you can insert a shortcode.
>
> Shortcodes are most commonly used by plugins to add functionality to a
>   WordPress site, without the need to write custom code. Essentially,
>   it's a shortcut to adding more advanced pieces of content.

You should be perfectly fine to use your shortcode.